# Which official US ad campaign encourages viewers to "choose to become a US citizen"?

Tags: citizenship

Not sure if this is quite on-topic here, but I'll try anyway. This is an ad-identification question.

We recently flew to the US via Logan Airport/Boston for vacation. Waiting for primary passport inspection in the blue line (for non-US-citizens), the screens there showed, among other things, an ad encouraging viewers to "choose to become a US citizen". It showed some happy people wrapped in US flags after their naturalization and highlighted some spoils of living in a democracy, such as freedom of expression. The ad also showed some "check your eligibility" URL, but I don't remember it.

As an EU citizen, I was quite impressed, because I can't quite imagine an EU country showing an equivalent ad in their passport inspection queue. I wanted to show that ad around but I haven't been able to rediscover it on the web.

Can someone identify this ad and provide a link? Given that it was shown to the passport inspection queue, I'm assuming it's some kind of official campaign, e. g., by the US government. I've tried searching the Web and YouTube, of course, but my search results are swamped by all kinds of other "become a US citizen" stuff. Thanks!

Comment: Doesthis ring a bell? https://www.uscis.gov/citizenship/outreach-tools/citizenship-public-education-and-awareness-campaign

Comment: @DimitriVulis Nope, that's not it. It was a much longer ad. But thanks anyway.

Comment: Could it have been either specific video for the airport, or an ad for an immigration law firm?

Comment: You might ask the airport itself, which surely knows who (or what entity) places ads on airport property.

Comment: @DJClayworth it would seem a bit weird to see an ad for a private company on a screen that otherwise shows "official" stuff (such as what to declare for customs) but who knows, maybe. It didn't seem airport specific, though.